# Amend a Mercurial commit without an editor window opening?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, git-amend

When I use mercurial command (`hg commit --amend`) it always opens up the editor window. In git I can avoid this by `git commit -a --amend -CHEAD`, is there something equivalent for mercurial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an experimental extension that was added to mercurial 4.3.1 called 'amend'. It performs the same action as commit --amend with the exception of not opening an edit window for the comments.

```
hg amend
```

It is marked as experimental, but I use it fairly often without any problems.

Also there is an `unamend` command that will 'undo the most recent amend operation on a current changeset'.

Comment: I didn't know about `hg amend`, this helped!

Answer (score 5):

Given that you have, and are using, `hg commit --amend`, the easiest way is to trick Mercurial into using an editor that does nothing, leaving the message file unchanged and hence usable:

```
$ hg --config ui.editor=true commit --amend
saved backup bundle to [long path redacted]
```

That is, Mercurial *did* open up an "editor window" (or editor command, anyway), it's just that this one—`/bin/true`—immediately said "everything worked" without touching the interactive terminal.

---

Note: if you have `HGEDITOR` set in your environment, this will actually override `ui.editor`:

```python
def geteditor(self):
    '''return editor to use'''
    if pycompat.sysplatform == 'plan9':
        # vi is the MIPS instruction simulator on Plan 9. We
        # instead default to E to plumb commit messages to
        # avoid confusion.
        editor = 'E'
    else:
        editor = 'vi'
    return (encoding.environ.get("HGEDITOR") or
            self.config("ui", "editor") or
            encoding.environ.get("VISUAL") or
            encoding.environ.get("EDITOR", editor))
```

so:

```
HGEDITOR=true hg commit --amend
```

will do the same thing more reliably (and with a bit less typing), but it's not called out this way in the documentation, which says only that `HGEDITOR` is deprecated.

Comment: For reasons which I cannot explain, this does not work for me on a Mac: `hg --config ui.editor=true commit --amend` produces
/bin/sh: aqua: command not found
abort: edit failed: aqua exited with status 127

Same thing with other variants, e.g.

`hg --config ui.editor=/usr/bin/true commit --amend` ;

`HGRCPATH= hg --config ui.editor=/usr/bin/true commit --amend`

Comment: @peak: Something is clearly overriding `ui.editor`. It appears (from the source) that `HGEDITOR` takes priority over the `ui.config` setting, despite this being documented as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Although `hg amend` is still marked experimental, I've never run into any problems using it.  However, it is worth noting that when using `hg commit`, one can always avoid the editor window by specifying a message. In the case of an amendment, it might make sense to retain the previous message, which can be done in several ways, but two robust methods are illustrated by the following:

```
hg commit --amend -m "$(hg log -l 1 --template '{desc}')" --date now

hg commit --amend -m "$(cat $(hg root)/.hg/last-message.txt)" --date now
```

For practical purposes, however, if your platform supports it, using HGEDITOR would be simpler:

```
HGEDITOR=true hg commit --amend --date now
```

Comment: Also worth noting: there's an extension called "evolve" that adds `hg amend` and uses the evolve feature's obsolescence markers to provide a safe way to edit history. This is a nice feature set but it still has not yet been put into any official Mercurial distribution.